# How to redirect/post from Owin OpenId Connect notifications?

Tags: asp.net, owin, openid-connect, identityserver3

I'm using Owin OpenId Connect Middleware together with Thinktecture Identity Server 4.

I was building authentication by this tutorial: https://www.scottbrady91.com/Identity-Server/Identity-Server-3-Standalone-Implementation-Part-3

My app is authenticating against Identity Server via Hybrid flow and it's all ok. 
The difference from example is that once I get the response from Identity Server and all the tokens, I don't want to actually login into the application where this middleware is being used. Instead I want to pass these parameters to other app and sign in user there. This middleware app should only serve as a middle man between Identity Server and the actual app (client).

I was wondering which notification in the whole pipeline is the best to put redirect and how to actually

Startup.cs:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
            new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {           

                /* Some parameters */                    
                Notifications =
                    new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
                    {   
                        MessageReceived = async n =>
                        {
                            //
                        },                            
                        AuthorizationCodeReceived = async n =>
                        {                                
                            //
                        },

                        SecurityTokenValidated = async n =>
                        {
                            //

                        }, 

                        RedirectToIdentityProvider = async n =>
                        {                                
                            //
                        }

                    }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on where you want to perform validation of the artifacts from the IDP.
MessageReceived is fired after the runtime determines a well-formed OIDC message has been received. SecurityTokenValidated is fired after the id_token (if it was in the message) was validated. AuthorizationCodeReceived will be fired after SecurityTokenValidated, this is your chance to redeem the 'code' for an 'access_token'. If you are redeeming a 'code', secrets are involved, which may come into play. RedirectToIdentityProvider is interesting when starting the Authorization flow, so not interesting.

Most likely: MessageReceived or SecurityTokenValidated.